# htmlentities and mysql_real_escape_string

Tags: mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is htmlentities() and mysql_real_escape_string() enough for cleaning user input in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4632663/is-htmlentities-and-mysql-real-escape-string-enough-for-cleaning-user-input)

In my site for the sql injecion i used mysql_real_escape_string but now suppose someone wants to enter PHP code in the forum so ised htmlentities function. my code is as below :

```
$not_con =mysql_real_escape_string(htmlentities($_POST['note']));
```

than i update sql db like

```
  mysql_query("UPDATE forumtopic set forumDescri='$not_con' WHERE forum_id=$f_id");
```

Now when i entered simple PHP code in textbox like `<?php echo "hi" ?>` than no proble its inserted into database succesfully.but
When i enter `<?php session_start(); echo "hi" ?>` it gives error like `FORBIDDEN you dont have permission 404 error`.help me in this

Comment: don't use `htmlentities` when you save into db, use it only when you display stuff.

Comment: but when session_start(); is in text then its not inserting into db...it give `Forbidden You don't have permission to access /forums/add_forum.php on this server.`

Comment: please give me solution.

Comment: For your access error I think you can change right on the file add_forum.php to 644 because apache is probably running with a different user.