# htmlentities mysql_real_escape_string

Tags: php, authentication

I just want to know if I'm doing it right.

***PHP***

```
<?php 
if(isset($_POST['email']) && isset($_POST['password'])) {
    $email = htmlentities(mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']));
    // then hash password
}
?>
```

***HTML***

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    <input type="email" name="email" />
    <input type="password" name="password" />
    <input type="submit" name="Login" />
</form>
```

is it good to do `htmlentities()` together with `mysql_real_escape_string`?
Or what do I need to do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [htmlentities and mysql_real_escape_string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11983757/htmlentities-and-mysql-real-escape-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say `htmlentities()` are good to prevent `XSS` attacks. So, if you're gonna re-render this data back to HTML format again, use it. If you're only worried about well-known `SQL Injection` attacks, I would say `mysql_real_escape_string()` is enough for you.

remember that you need to decode HTML entities, once you're gonna show them again.

Comment: heheeh! i'm just wondering what to use between those two.. thanks again..

Comment: for something like email address, if you just want to store it on the database and show it on the user profile, don't use htmlentities(). But if it's a comment on a blog, or something more possibly to contain HTML reserved characters, then it's better to use it. :)